# For Loop with button prompt input

Tags: javascript, for-loop, leaflet

I have a map with a button and when the button is clicked it prompts the user to enter a unit of measurement. Based off what the user enters, the popup should display the population density based on that unit of measurement (eg. mile, km, hectare).

I got it this to work as a function, but now I need to convert it to a for loop (per homework requirements), and it isn't working properly. Firstly, the markers are displaying on the map before the button is even clicked, and originally I had 
"Population density: "+density[i]..." under the var popup and it was working but only displaying the hectare population density (from the `else` statement).

```
var cities = ['Fort Wayne', 'Indianapolis', 'South Bend'];
var coord = [[41.0793, -85.1394], [39.7684, -86.1581], [41.6764, -86.2520]];
var pop = [265904, 872680, 102245];
var areaMi = [110.62, 368.2, 41.46];
var areaKm = [286.5, 954, 107.38];
var areaHa = [28700, 96350, 10830];
var density = [];
var pleaseWork = [];

var options = {
        center: [40.4864, -86.1336],
        zoom: 7.4
}

var map = L.map('map', options);

var tiles = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.wmflabs.org/bw-mapnik/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
});
map.addLayer(tiles);

var button = document.getElementById("map-cities"); 

button.addEventListener("click", function() {

    do {
        var units = prompt('Enter the units for calculating density', 'Enter "mile", "km" or "hectare".');
    } while (units != "mile" && units != "km" && units != "hectare");

    pleaseWork.push(units);
});

for(var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {

    if (pleaseWork[i] === "km") { 
        popup += "<Population density</b>: "+density.push(pop[i]/areaKm[i])}
    else if (pleaseWork[i] === "mile") { 
        popup += "<Population density</b>: "+density.push(pop[i]/areaMi[i])}
    else {popup += "<Population density</b>: "+density.push(pop[i]/areaHa[i])};

    var popup = "<b>"+cities[i]+"</b><br>"
            +"<b>population</b>: "+pop[i].toLocaleString();


    L.marker([coord[i][0],coord[i][1]])
            .addTo(map)   
            .bindPopup(popup);

}
```

Comment: Well it shows before because you are not really waiting for it. Your loop is eventless at the bottom of the code. `cities` are prefilled even if `pleaseWork` are not. Replace `i < cities.length` with `i < pleaseWork.length`.

Comment: I tried that and all of my markers disappeared, even after trying the button and input, they would not re-appear.

Comment: Well, you have to call the loop at the end of the click event.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you elaborate?

Comment: Actually, I think I figured it out. Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad to hear. If the issue is solved, I suggest to remove the question.